# Able to choose beyond max date when navigate by year in datepicker(Android)

Tags: android, datepicker

I am able to select date beyond MAX date when i navigate by Year.

Requirement:
I should allow user to select Today's date plus 365 days in datepicker.
So Min Date = Today, 
Max date = Today plus 364

Problem:
Able to choose beyond max date when navigate by year

Steps to reproduce issue:

1. Today's date is selected (eg: 25-oct-2019)
2. Select a date which is 5 days from today(eg: 30-oct-2019)
3. Select year and go to next year (eg: 2020)
4. You will see 24-oct-2020 is selected, as that was our MAX date
5. But when you click ok, onDate selected will give you a date in beyond max date(eg: 30-oct-2020)

```
private void showDatePicker(Calendar selectedDate) {
        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                        MainActivity.this.onDateSet(year, month, day);
                    }
                },
                selectedDate.get(YEAR),
                selectedDate.get(MONTH),
                selectedDate.get(DAY_OF_MONTH));
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(today.getTimeInMillis() - 1000);
        today.add(DATE, 365);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(today.getTimeInMillis());

        datePickerDialog.setButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                datePickerDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }

    public void onDateSet(int year, int month, int day) {
        String date = String.valueOf(year).concat("-").concat(String.valueOf(month).concat("-").concat(String.valueOf(day)));
        btnDate.setText(date);
    }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it more understandable with screenshots?

Comment: If you want to workaround this bug, you can compare the returned value to the max value, and if it's higher, replace it with max value.

Comment: I did the same workaround, just thought of confirming any other better solution. Anyways thanks for the help

Comment: My only suggestions would be: (i) consider using [310ABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) for Dates; and (ii) I don't think you need to override the cancel behaviour (dismiss should be the default). I see you already [reported it to Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143335470) - good job! :)

Comment: ...though I can also see it's already reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124647440